# What kind of bamboo is this?

Tags: identification

I have a bamboo species in my backyard I would like to identify.  Its a mid level running bamboo with shoots that hit 1 inch thickness near the base and grows up to 20-25 feet at this time.  It has only been planted for a year and a few months so not sure if the shoots will get higher next growing season.  There are also about 12 inches between joints on the shoots too.  I would also like to say this species grows very well here in Phoenix AZ and with a good watering once a week and twice or more in the hott summer months where the temps are up around 110F+

I am asking about this species to find out if its edible for pets and domesticated animals.  Once I identify the species I am hoping i can answer this second set of questions.  It links to this reference on this post at [Pets StackExchange](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/7234/3424)

Here is a photos of a leaf group and a shoot.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what variety of bamboo this is, haven't checked, but I can tell you that you should not allow rabbits to eat bamboo shoots - they are toxic for them. If you intend to allow your rabbits free rein in the garden, you will need to fence off the bamboo.

Answer (score 1):

I have this bamboo. It is a crawling variety, that is it grows lateral in springtime also sending shoots up as it sprawls. Each shoot will grow to its full height in one season if the conditions are good.

Cutting the runners (which are underground) will provide more nutrients to the main group of trees (which are really giant grasses). If you thin out the canes, the larger diameter should begin to appear. Full sized canes will not grow larger,only producing more and more leaves. My cats regularly chew on mine and dont get sick.

Bamboo's come in 'grouping' and 'crawling' varieties and should be contained if you do not want them to spread. Grouping stands get around 30 feet in diameter on their own whilst the crawling varieties spread 30 feet and up to 45 feet away, sending shoots along the way.

Comment: this is interesting but does not answer the question..

Comment: I appreciate that answer, but do you know the scientific name for this species?  the bamboo is doing exactly as you are stating here.  Though in the Phoenix hot climate (our summers) I am surprised to say it is staying very robust in the extreme heat too (110+ F).

Answer (score 1):

Most juvenile bamboo are difficult to identify by the leaves or canes.  I have 20 plus bamboo plants and your picture of the leaves could match more than half of them.  The simplest method is to identify the shoot when it first emerges from the soil.  This should put you in the ballpark but you will have to look through a few hundred pictures.  Once you have it narrowed down by the shoot identification, you can further narrow it down by seeing which ones stand up to high ambient heat.   Hopes this helps.

Comment: When I look at a shoot, what am I looking for? size of growth in 24 hours? Diameter? Color?...?